# check if value is present anywhere in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new feature ["EnglishName"] for my feature passenger["Surname"] that occurs anwywhere in another dataframe consisting of a single column containing common English Surnames (surnames["Name"]).

I am struggling to find the right output.

this code gives output but it gives "False" for every Surnames, even the ones that are present in "name"

```
passenger["EnglishName"] = passenger["Surname"]==(surnames["name"].any())
```

I thought I could fix this with a lambda expression, but I have not been able to figure out the right format

```
passenger["EnglishName"] = passenger["Surname"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.isin(surnames["name"].any()))
```

I have searched Stackoverflow for similar code, but they often have to do with SQL kind of syntax (matching two dataframes) or the data is not present in a dataframe and you can use .isin without a problem.

What is the right code to anwser this simple question?
You help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include [`reproducible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4985099)

Comment: `passenger["EnglishName"] = passenger["Surname"].isin(surnames["name"].tolist())` or  `passenger["EnglishName"]  = passenger["Surname"].where(passenger["Surname"].isin(surnames["name"].tolist()))`?

Comment: Thank you! adding .tolist() to the code solved the problem

Comment: `.tolist()` works because the comparison is not made based on the series index